# how to get count of the repeated words in a sentence in python

Tags: python

> s = " power n power_point boot bootstrap angularJs power N Power_point BootStrap Boot n angularJs Bootstrap " \
>       "angular n Angularjs hjg gyhjk tueirwe Power Power_point Bootstrap"
>   power n power_point - 2
>   n angularJs - 2

Comment: input is                                                                                                             s = " power n power_point boot bootstrap angularJs power N Power Power_point BootStrap Boot n angularJs Bootstrap angular n Angularjs hjg gyhjk tueirwe Power Power_point Bootstrap"
output is
 power n power_point --------------------------2
n angularJs ----------------------------- 2

Comment: please give me any solution for this question